# biboptions not recognized

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I have been using elsarticle.cls  for most of my work. Now I am trying to take those papers and put them into a thesis, using a thesis template given by my school. The elsarticle says in the preamble

```
%% natbib.sty is loaded by default. However, natbib options can be
%% provided with \biboptions{...} command. Following options are
%% valid:

%%   round  -  round parentheses are used (default)
%%   square -  square brackets are used   [option]
%%   curly  -  curly braces are used      {option}
%%   angle  -  angle brackets are used    <option>
%%   semicolon  -  multiple citations separated by semi-colon (default)
%%   colon  - same as semicolon, an earlier confusion
%%   comma  -  separated by comma
%%   authoryear - selects author-year citations (default)
%%   numbers-  selects numerical citations
%%   super  -  numerical citations as superscripts
%%   sort   -  sorts multiple citations according to order in ref. list
%%   sort&compress   -  like sort, but also compresses numerical citations
%%   compress - compresses without sorting
%%   longnamesfirst  -  makes first citation full author list
%%
%% \biboptions{longnamesfirst,comma}

\biboptions{sort&compress}
```

Since I am using the mitthesis.cls instead of elsarticle.cls now, I tried to load natbib using:

```
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
```

This seems to work (I think?), but if I try to use `\biboptions{sort&compress}`, I get an error:

```
Undefined control sequence \biboptions
```

Any ideas on how to get `\biboptions{sort&compress}` to work?

Also, am I loading natbib correctly (I want to use a numbered bibiliography style like `\bibliographystyle{model1a-num-names}`).

Comment: `biboptions` is a special command provided by `elsarticle`. You can directly pass all options to `natbib` -> `\usepackage[sort&compress]{natbib}`

Comment: Perfect, If you make that an answer I can select it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`elsarticle` defines `biboptions` and passes everything to package `natbib`. You can pass all options you formerly used to `natbib` directly:

```
\usepackage[sort&compress]{natbib}
```