# Citation error in using BibTeX "Paragraph ended before \@citex was complete"

Tags: bibtex, natbib, cite-package

I am getting an error when I use BibTeX bibliography.
I used `\usepackage{natbib}` and `\usepackage{cite}`
when I compile the file, I get the error

```
Paragraph ended before \@citex was complete
```

and part of the paragraph located after the citation disappears
also, I get the message

```
I suspect you've forgotten a '}', causing me to apply this control sequence to too much text
```

I am using IEEE tran style with the commands:

```
\bibliography{library}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
```

can you help me with this ?

I have just downloaded a new IEEE template, but the same problem appears.

Answer (score 50):

The `cite` and `natbib` packages are both redefining the same things and are not compatible with each other: you need to choose one or the other. As you are using the `IEEEtranN` (a `natbib` style) it seems likely you'll want something like

```
\usepackage[numbers,super]{natbib}
```

and simply remove `\usepackage{cite}`.  (One can also load `natbib` with no options and set the style using `\setcitestyle{numbers,super}`.)

Comment: Thank you.Now the error disappeared when I removed \usepackage{cite}, and using natbib as you suggested.  But, I am getting the citation as a superscript question mark, and the paper title is not shown in the References. Is there any additional thing I can do ?

Comment: @user3780383 If you don't want superscript references, don't use the `super` keyword. The inclusion of the article title is down to the BibTeX style (`IEEEtran`), not related to using `cite` or `natbib`.

Comment: removing the \usepackage{cite} worked for me while using the ACM-Reference-Format

Comment: Joseph Wright's answer recommends removing `\usepackage{cite}`. You won't believe it, I got the same error message too, but because this package **was not enabled**! I used the standard Latex template set of a respected old scientific journal, and there was no directive `\usepackage{cite}` in it. After activating this package, all my links worked, which was not the case before. Moreover, the message concerning the specified error has disappeared.

Comment: `IEEEtran.bst` is not a `natbib` style but there is an `IEEEtranN.bst` which is (http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex/README).  The `IEEEtran` class is designed with the expectation that it can be used with `cite` package.

Comment: Could you say which class/template?

Comment: Comptes Rendus Chimie. Interestingly, there are no problems when working online through Overleaf. Maybe this package is included there by default. However, editing online is not very comfortable. When I tried to use Texmaker, the error messages started.

Comment: It's very easy to miss [errors on Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/Tips_and_Tricks_for_Troubleshooting_LaTeX), or could be due to different TeX versions. The class should load `cite` through the `CRCHIM` class option (which does a few things) but if something goes wrong it may require manual loading. Feel free to ask a question if you're still curious.

Comment: This may have given you the same error, the cause of the OP is definitely loading `natbib` and `cite` simultaneously, which (depending on the `.bst`) can also be resolved by using `cite` and not loading `natbib`.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error:

```
Paragraph ended before \@citex was complete
```

There was simply a brace `}` missed and LaTeX considers the whole paragraph as a BibTeX key citation!!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Where was the missing brace (in the bib or tex file, affecting which macro)?  Could you add a snippet from the example which affected you? Given `}` are required all over the place in TeX, it's helpful to associate the missing brace with other commands to narrow down the search.

Answer (score 2):

Beyond removing `\usepackage{cite}`, you can use

```
\biboptions{sort&compress}
```

to preserve the same functionality.

Comment: See [biboptions not recognized](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/235298/106162)